# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
....linq code
select new OrderList
{
Requestor = f.Name,
Amount = b.TotalInclAmount,
DateOrder =  b.DateOrder.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); // This line cause this issue
}
```

When I execute the above query I got the following exception.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

When I search through the StackOverflow about this issue most of the answer recommended to use **AsEnumerable** But In my case, the table is much bigger. when i used it, it cause performance issue.

advise me to achieve this using without AsEnumerable.

Comment: Keep your dates as dates!

Comment: Thank you. Before doing this I want to check others comment too.

Comment: Load it as a date, call `AsEnumerable()` on the result, and *then* write another `Select()` which formats it into your desired string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the presentation in the UI, not in the business layer. So, leave it as DateTime and let the UI format it. It tries to interpret the `ToString` to the query, which isn't available.

You still should stick to the `IQueryable<T>` and dates as datetimes, because you can add conditions to the query before it is being persist. (for example a `where` on `DateOrder`)

Comment: You probably meant `IQueryable<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.